# Principal Component Analysis handled multicolinearity in data

Tags: pca, multicollinearity

How principal component analysis handled high multicolinearity in data set?

Comment: The question is too scarce informationally. Besides, what is "high" multicollinearity? Why do you think PCA has problems with multicollinearity?

Comment: Well, one of the purposes of PCA is to find the weights(aka loadings) that will project the data in a way that the new variables have least correlation.